# Cannot debug C# RTD Server project in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: c#, excel, com, rtd

As part of an attempt to figure out the various issues working with (previously) working .NET COM projects and Excel 2013 on my machine, I created a simple test C# RTDServer class in Visual Studio 2013.  Creating the test RTD Server project helped me realize that my Excel 2013 was a 64 bit version and that I needed to set Target Platform to x64 for any .NET COM components to work with this version of Excel.

This test RTD component works fine (as long as it is compiled as x64), but I cannot Debug into the code using Visual Studio.  What used to work on older projects is to set the Start-Up Application to Excel.exe and then I could always hit a break point in the `ServerStart(IRTDUpdateEvent CallbackObject)` method, for example.

However when I try this with VS 2013 project, it never hits the break point.  If I set a new break point while it is running I see the message:

> The breakpoint will not currently be hit.  No symbols have been loaded
>   for this document.

I have searched a lot for the solution to this, but not found anything that worked yet.

Comment: When you debugging, check the Module window and see if your exe loads the DLL at the right path.

Comment: @Matt: The Modules window is completely empty when the Debugger is running.  (The way I am starting the Debugger is by hitting the *Play* button.)  So what is happening, is the Debugger starts up Excel and loads the Worksheet with the RTD links, but it seems not to load the DLL at all.

Comment: @Matt: one more point - since the DLL is being accessed via COM, it seems like the Debugger is not really attaching the DLL to the Excel process.  (But if I stop the Debugger it shuts down Excel as you would expect.)

Comment: Are you sure you're debugging the right process?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out this problem was caused by an app config for Excel which we had to use when running with Excel 2003 (when we first developed this app).

The config contained the following:

```
 <startup>

 <supportedRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>

 <supportedRuntime version="v1.1.4322"/>

 <requiredRuntime version="v2.0.50727"/>

 </startup>
```

However, this RTD Server was using .NET 4.5.  Once I deleted the config file from the Office directory, it started working in debugger.